SSH no such file or directory, ansible problem
Я попытался запустить плейбук ansible, но у меня возникла такая проблема:
1 скриншот - главная машина ansible (ip - 192.168.0.5/24)
2 скриншот - ansbile_inventory
3 скриншот - главная машина ssh_conf
4 скриншот - главная машина openssh
5 скриншот - CLI cannot find public key (ip - 192.168.0.102/24)
6 скриншот - CLI ssh_conf
7 скриншот - ALTwks ssh_conf (ip 192.168.0.101/24)
https://i.sstatic.net/CU21zenr.png
https://i.sstatic.net/G9q6P5QE.png
https://i.sstatic.net/BH3cbpaz.png
https://i.sstatic.net/njH7YFPN.png
https://i.sstatic.net/FFSAxYVo.png
https://i.sstatic.net/gwFRWS5I.png
https://i.sstatic.net/pBHXHgWf.png
К сожалению, я не решил проблему с ключом, поэтому я решил удалить на удаленных машинах публичные ssh-ключи (и, к сожалению, на главной машине тоже) Я удалил их, но столкнулся со странной проблемой. Удаленные машины не видели нового ключа, сгенерированного на главной машине, но каждая машина могла подключиться к главной машине: ssh user@192.168.0.5 -p 3322, но не через root.
Проблема в том, что мне нужно получить открытый ключ с главной машины, но удаленные машины не видят путь, где находится ключ с главной машины, тогда я пробую: ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub user@192.168.0.5 -p 3322.
Но они могут подключиться к Г (кстати, если после подключения к главной машине я пытаюсь перейти в другое место, ничего не происходит).
Я пробовал удалять данные в known_host и authorized_hosts, но это не помогло, я пробовал удалять ключи

Что за бред? ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/root/.ssh/id_ed25519. Вы запускаете ansible от пользователя root?

Да, запускаю от рута

А можно текст запостить как текст, а не картинки? Тебе самому-то удобно кликать по ссылкам и рассматривать ШГ?
